# Unable to configure virtual hosts on apache2 under windows 7 - returns 403 error

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, hosts

Good time of day!
I successfully used apache + php on windows 7, but now I desided to make a couple of virtual hosts. I added to the end of apache config such section:

```
<virtualhost> 
ServerAdmin yourmail@domain.com 
ServerName jiifirst 
DocumentRoot "c :/ apache2/web/jiifirst/htdocs" 
ScriptAlias ​​/ cgi-bin / "c :/ apache2/web/jiifirst/cgi-bin /" 
ErrorLog c :/ apache2 / web / jiifirst / logs / error.log 
CustomLog c :/ apache2/web/jiifirst/logs/access.log common 
</ virtualhost>
```

Then created the appropriate folders. However when I try to call http://127.0.0.2/test.php 
such error appears:

> error Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access / test.php on this server.

At the same time I can still access localhost without problems. I have also changed rights to the folders. What apache settings should I change to fix this problem?

Comment: Apache. Windows 7.  No responses. Surprised?

Comment: I was surprised so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, what's with all the spaces in the configuration? E.g. `"c :/ apache2/web/jiifirst/htdocs"`.  That's not your real config; how did you cut and paste this?

Secondly, you're talking to the server as `http://127.0.0.2`. Yes, that is the server's IP address, but in HTTP (at least 1.1 and later), an address means more than just identifying a network card on a machine. It identifies a web site domain. The address goes *into* the protocol, and the web server can decide which web site to provide to the client (at the same IP address).

Your `VirtualHost` defines a web site whose domain name is `jiifirst`. This does not match the IP-based access `127.0.0.2`.

However, can still match the `VirtualHost` anyway. Your `VirtualHost` is missing the address and port match fields, but if it looks something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

it means that it's possible for the `VirtualHost` to match an IP based request from any address to port 80. If Apache cannot find an exact match for the host name among any of the `VirtualHost` entries, (and you have no special default VirtualHost), it will choose the first one in order of appearance that has a match on the address.

The lack of an address on `<VirtualHost>` may be the reason why things are not happening (and possibly the spaces, if they are indeed real).

Answer (score 0):

The real solution of my problem was in section

Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all

I just had to change Deny from all to Allow from all
Now everything works pretty good!